# in which base is the number 221 the factor of 1215

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

I basically tried to find a number $n$ which would be the base and then divide both the numbers $221$ and $1215$ so as to get a combo which has same remainder
But I am not able to proceed in doing so.
Help would be appreciated

Comment: Are both these numbers in base n?

Comment: Regarding the title: a number is a factor of another regardless of the base in which they are written. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 2  \left(   x^{3}  + 2 x^{2}  +  x  + 5 \right)  =  \left(  2 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot  \left(     x  + 1   \right)    -  x  + 9     $$

so try base $9$

We have
$$ 221_{nine} = 181  $$
$$ 1215_{nine} = 905   $$
As both are odd, it did no damage when I multiplied the larger number by $2$

Comment: Yeah ,it's working for base 9,.. But could you elaborate what you did ? @WillJagy

Answer (score 0):

I wrote small python script to test all of the relevant bases

```
# what base is 221 a factor of 1215

snumber="221"
sother="1215"

def todecimal(input,base):
    output=0
    for i in range(len(input)):
        output=output+int(input[i])*(base**(len(input)-1-i))
    return output

for i in range(2,300):#starting at five is better cause largest number given is five,but 2 can be used anywhere if you want to test for other numbers.
    if((todecimal(sother,i)%todecimal(snumber,i))==0):
        print(i)
```

Its basically brute forcing it for the first 300 bases but you can test for any 2 numbers. Just change the input, dont need to import anything , any python 3 ide will be able to run this.